# Scraping Instagram reply comments using the Puppeteer library in Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am currently scraping comments on Instagram using Puppeteer in Node.js. I am able to retrieve the comments, but I am still unsure about how to scrape the reply on comments, as shown in this example.

[image]

here is my current code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const getComment = async ({ link }) => {
    const mainResponse = {};
    const comments = [];
    const launchOptions = {
        headless: false
    }
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    page.on('response', async (response) => {
        if (response.url().includes('graphql')) {
            const responseText = await response.text();
            let lines = responseText.split('\n');
            comments.push(lines);
        }
    });

    mainResponse.comments = comments;
    
    await page.goto(link);

    await browser.close();
    return mainResponse;
}
```

So, my code uses the browser's response to identify the data I receive. The question is, is it possible to retrieve the reply on comments?

Comment: What's `link`, please?

Comment: link in my code is instagram post URL